# How can i write x00 in file.bin c++ ofstream::write

Tags: c++, ofstream, bin

The problem is that i can't initialize the INODE->NAME is behaving unexpected. In the column 0B the result is FF, but i want 00. What i am doing wrong?
What a really want is to write a value that is smaller than sizeof(INODE[i].NAME), but the bytes that i did not fill with the value should be 00 and not random!

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char IS_USED;             
    unsigned char IS_DIR;              
    char NAME[10];                     
    char SIZE;                         
    unsigned char DIRECT_BLOCKS[3];    
    unsigned char INDIRECT_BLOCKS[3];
    unsigned char DOUBLE_INDIRECT_BLOCKS[3];
} INODE;
```

```
ofstream fileSystem(fsFileName, ios::out | ios::binary);

// in this case numblocks is 1

// Writing INODES
    for (int i = 0; i < numBlocks; i++) {
        char empty[] = {'/', '\x00'};
        if (i == 0) {
            cout << sizeof(empty) << endl;
            strcpy(node[i].NAME, empty);
            node[i].IS_USED = 0x01;
            node[i].IS_DIR = 0x01;
        } else {
            strcpy(node[i].NAME, "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00");
            node[i].IS_USED = 0x00;
            node[i].IS_DIR = 0x00;
        }
        node[i].SIZE = 0x00;
        node[i].DIRECT_BLOCKS[0] = 0x00;
        node[i].DIRECT_BLOCKS[1] = 0x00;
        node[i].DIRECT_BLOCKS[2] = 0x00;
        node[i].INDIRECT_BLOCKS[0] = 0x00;
        node[i].INDIRECT_BLOCKS[1] = 0x00;
        node[i].INDIRECT_BLOCKS[2] = 0x00;
        node[i].DOUBLE_INDIRECT_BLOCKS[0] = 0x00;
        node[i].DOUBLE_INDIRECT_BLOCKS[1] = 0x00;
        node[i].DOUBLE_INDIRECT_BLOCKS[2] = 0x00;
        fileSystem.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&node[i]), sizeof(INODE));
    }
```

This is my file.bin

[image: This is my file.bin]

Comment: `strcpy` only copies the number of actual string bytes, and the string terminator character.   It does not zero the rest of the buffer it is copying to.  It does not even _know_ what size that buffer is (and this is one of the inherent dangers with `strcpy` and why `strncpy` is preferred).  If you wish your entire buffer to be zero, just use `memset`.  Or, since you're using C++, `std::fill`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!